# Array of hashes

Tags: perl, hash

In perl , i have an array of hashes
like

```
0  HASH(0x98335e0)
   'title' => 1177
   'author' => 'ABC'
   'quantity' => '-100'


1  HASH(0x832a9f0)
   'title' => 1177
   'author' => 'ABC'
   'quantity' => '100'

2  HASH(0x98335e0)
   'title' => 1127
   'author' => 'DEF'
   'quantity' => '5100'


3  HASH(0x832a9f0)
   'title' => 1277
   'author' => 'XYZ'
   'quantity' => '1030'
```

Now I need to accumulate the quantity where title and author are same.
In the above structure for hash with title = 1177 and author ='ABC' quantity can be accumulated into one and the entire structure should looks like below

```
0  HASH(0x98335e0)
   'title' => 1177
   'author' => 'ABC'
   'quantity' => 0

1  HASH(0x98335e0)
   'title' => 1127
   'author' => 'DEF'
   'quantity' => '5100'

2  HASH(0x832a9f0)
   'title' => 1277
   'author' => 'XYZ'
   'quantity' => '1030'
```

What is the best way i can do this accumulation so that it is optimised? Number of array elements can be very large. I dont mind adding an extra key to the hash to aid the same , but i dont want n lookups . Kindly advise

Comment: You say "i dont want n lookups", but there's no way to accumulate across the entire array without accessing every member of the array.

Comment: Please add [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) and [perldoc perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) to your reading list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my %sum;
for (@a) {
  $sum{ $_->{author} }{ $_->{title} } += $_->{quantity};
}

my @accumulated;
foreach my $author (keys %sum) {
  foreach my $title (keys %{ $sum{$author} }) {
    push @accumulated => { title    => $title,
                           author   => $author,
                           quantity => $sum{$author}{$title},
                         };
  }
}
```

Not sure whether `map` makes it look nicer:

```
my @accumulated =
  map {
    my $author = $_;
    map { author   => $author,
          title    => $_,
          quantity => $sum{$author}{$_},
        },
      keys %{ $sum{$author} };
  }
  keys %sum;
```

Comment: This sample is just itching for some map/grep love

Comment: @Daenyth Usually yes, but it doesn't look so nice in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want N lookups, then you need a *hash* function -- however you need to *store* them with that hash function. By the time you have them in a list (or array), it's too late. You either get lucky, ***all the time***, or you're going to have N lookups.

***Or*** *insert* them into the hash <s>above</s>below. A hybrid solution is to store a locator as item 0 in the list/array.

```
my $lot = get_lot_from_whatever();
my $tot = $list[0]{ $lot->{author} }{ $lot->{title} };
if ( $tot ) { 
    $tot->{quantity} += $lot->{quantity};
}
else { 
    push @list, $list[0]{ $lot->{author} }{ $lot->{title} } = $lot;
}
```

---

*previous*

First of all we'll reformat that to make it readable.

```
[ { title => 1177, author => 'ABC', quantity => '-100' }
, { title => 1177, author => 'ABC', quantity => '100'  }
, { title => 1127, author => 'DEF', quantity => '5100' }
, { title => 1277, author => 'XYZ', quantity => '1030' }
]
```

Next, you need to break down the problem. You want quantities of things grouped
by author and title. So you need those things to *uniquely* identify those lots.
To repeat, you want a combination of *names* to identify *entities*. Thus, you
will need a hash that identifies things by names.

Since we have two things, a double hash is a good way to do it.

```
my %hash;
foreach my $lot ( @list ) {
    $hash{ $lot->{author} }{ $lot->{title} } += $lot->{quantity};
}
# consolidated by hash
```

To turn this back into a list, we need to unbundle the levels.

```
my @consol
    = sort { $a->{author} cmp $b->{author} || $a->{title} cmp $b->{title} }
      map  { 
          my ( $a, $titles ) = @$_; # $_ is [ $a, {...} ]
          map { +{ title => $_, author => $a, quantity => $titles->{$_} }
          keys %$titles;
      } 
      map  { [ $_ => $hash{$_} ] } # group and freeze a pair
      keys %hash
    ;

# consolidated in a list.
```

And there you have it back, I even sorted it for you. Of course you could also 
sort this by--publishers being what they are--descending quantities.

```
sort {  $b->{quantity} <=> $a->{quantity} 
     || $a->{author}   cmp $b->{author} 
     || $a->{title}    cmp $b->{title} 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is important to step back and consider the source of the data. If the data are coming from a database, then you should write the SQL query so that it gives you one row for each author/title combination with the total quantity in the quantity field. If you are reading the data from a file, then you should either read it directly into a hash or use [Tie::IxHash](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Tie::IxHash) if order is important.

Once you have the data in an array of hashrefs like you do, you will have to create an auxiliary data structure and do a whole bunch of lookups, the cost of which may well dominate the running time of your program (not in a way it matters if it is run for 15 minutes once a day) and you might run into memory issues.